# JavaScript variables scope and underscore.js

Tags: javascript

I have a function, with this inside it:

```
var fobj = function(){};

var my_obj = fobj.extend({
    test: function(){
        this.year = 1999;  
        my_fmagic.doMagic([
            {
                field: 'year', 
                type: 'function', 
                value: function(data_from_doMagic){

                    console.log(data_from_doMagic, this.year);

                    return data_from_doMagic == this.year;
                }
            }
        ]);
    }
});
```

Then, the `doMagic` function:

```
var fmagic = function(){};

var my_fmagic = fmagic.extend({
    doMagic: function( rules ) {
        var data_from_doMagic = 1999;
        _.each(rules, function(rule) { 
            switch(rule.type) {
                case "function":
                    var f = _.wrap(rule.value, function(func){
                        return func( data_from_doMagic );
                    });
                    f();
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The idea is: pass an array of "rules" to `doMagic` and let it do the rest.

Expected result: `test()` should return `true` (well, in this example it won't return anything, obviously, because there's no return, but the `value` field of the rule should be `true`.)

Problem: Instead the result being `true` it's `false`, because the function `f()` in `doMagic` doesn't know what the variable `year` is, and so it compares "1999" with "undefined".

As you can see I know where the problem is, but I can't think about any solution.

Ideas?

Regards

Comment: I don't know underscore.js, but in your debugger place a breakpoint on the line `return data_from_doMagic == year;`. Does the script ever reach that point? And if it does, what's the value of `year`?

Comment: The code presented works correctly if you call `f`: http://jsbin.com/exaqad There's no scope issue. The function you're passing as `value` clearly has access to `year` because it closes over the context in which `year` is defined, and similarly the wrapper function has access to `data_from_doMagic` for the same reason.

Comment: No, sorry for not being clear. This a simple example, and test() lives inside a BackboneJS View. The doMagic lives inside another library.  @T.J. Crowder f() get's called inside doMagic(), after declaring that variable. (I had a typo in the question). Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4J2E8/

Comment: @alexandernst: Your fiddle is just a copy of the above, without even the `f()` you've now added to the question, and throws an `Unexpected identifier` error (probably because you didn't include backbone). The idea is to **demonstrate the problem**.

Comment: Yes, I thought you only need to see part of the code. Making an entire runnable code will take me a while as I need to create a Model, bind it to the View, etc. Give me some time.

Comment: Also, not relevant to the problem, but IMO explicitly relying on type conversion in the equality is a little sketchy--pick a data type.

Comment: Ok, here's a working (or maybe I should say non-working) example: http://jsfiddle.net/k2awe/   Turn on the dev console and you'll see "1999 undefined". That means that "year" variable is in another scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted to your *(original)* question was ***fundamentally different*** from the code you ended up showing in your fiddle demonstrating the problem.

The problem is here:

```
test: function(){
    this.year = 1999;  // <=== This isn't a variable, as you originally showed
    my_fmagic.doMagic([
        {
            field: 'year', 
            type: 'function', 
            value: function(data_from_doMagic){

                // *** `this` here won't be the same as `this` was above ***

                console.log(data_from_doMagic, this.year);

                return data_from_doMagic == this.year;
            }
        }
    ]);
}
```

The quick fix is:

```
test: function(){
    var self = this;   // <=== Create a variable to close over

    this.year = 1999;

    my_fmagic.doMagic([
        {
            field: 'year', 
            type: 'function', 
            value: function(data_from_doMagic){

                console.log(data_from_doMagic, self.year); // <== And use it here

                return data_from_doMagic == self.year;     // <== And use it here
            }
        }
    ]);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2awe/1/)

This happens because in JavaScript, `this` is determined entirely by how a function is *called*, not where it's defined. When calling the function you're passing as `value`, `this` will be the global object (`window`, on browsers) because the code is doing nothing to tell the engine what `this` should be.

So to solve it, the easy answer is to create a variable in the context of the call to the `test` function and assign it the value of `this`; then we use that variable (`self`) rather than `this` within the `value` function, because the `value` function closes over the context of the call to `test`.

More to explore *(disclosure: these are all from my blog)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Ah, that one was a really silly one :(   Thank you, it works correctly!

Comment: @alexandernst: We've all done something like it in our time. :-) Glad that helped,